# What is the fastest way to convert a XML response in charset=iso-8859-1 to JSON in charset=UTF-8 in an API Proxy

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, apigee

I'm developing an API proxy in Apigee EDGE to expose a Target API in SOAP (XML) to a REST/JSON endpoint with a fairly simple **XMLtoJSON** and a **AssignMessage** policy.
Until I just noticed that some characters in the final JSON were displayed as "**?**" while in the original SOAP (XML) response the same characters were correctly displayed as "**á**" for example.

Then I noticed that the response from the Target API endpoint came in as:

```
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=iso-8859-1
```

While my intention is to output a properly encoded UTF-8 response as:

```
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
```

So my question is: Is there a way to convert the character encoding from iso-8859-1 to UTF-8 using just standard Policies? without incurring in going to Node, Java, Javascript or Python policies to do this simple character encoding?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just set the appropriate encoding in a Content-Type header on the response using the AssignMessage policy...  Does that work?